# Issue with xsd:decimal when estimating the radius

Tags: xsd, sparql, rdf, owl, fuseki

I want to extract items that are located within 20 km of the given latitude and longitude. Below I provide my query. The only issue that it has is related to `?lat` and `?long`. They have the format like this `"41.3823035"^^xsd:decimal`. In the ontology file, latitude and longitude have the format `xsd:float`. 
When I run the query, I get the error:

```
Error 500: Infinite or NaN
Fuseki - version 2.4.1 (Build date: 2016-11-04T18:59:20+0000)
```

If I substitute `?lat` by 41.38, and `?long` by `2.22`, then it works.

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.test.com/my-ontology.owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX oo:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX oa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/oa#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX lfn: <http://www.dotnetrdf.org/leviathan#>
PREFIX fn: <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
PREFIX afn: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/function#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?id ?kwds ?lat WHERE {
    ?p owl:id 123 .
    ?p rdf:type ?service .
    ?service rdfs:subClassOf ?family .
    ?otherService rdfs:subClassOf ?family .
    ?item rdf:type ?otherService .
    ?item owl:id ?id .
    ?item owl:latitude ?lat .
    ?item owl:longitude ?long .
    BIND ((lfn:degrees-to-radians(?lat)) AS ?lat1) .
    BIND ((lfn:degrees-to-radians(?long)) AS ?lon1) .
    BIND ((lfn:degrees-to-radians(41.384697)) AS ?lat2) .
    BIND ((lfn:degrees-to-radians(2.150849)) AS ?lon2) .
    BIND ((?lon2-?lon1) AS ?dlon) .
    BIND ((?lat2-?lat1) AS ?dlat) .
    BIND ((lfn:sq(lfn:sin(?dlat/2))+lfn:cos(?lat1)*lfn:cos(?lat2)*lfn:sin(?dlon/2) ) AS ?a) .
    BIND ((2*lfn:sin-1(lfn:sqrt(?a))) AS ?c) .
    BIND ((xsd:float(fn:round((6371*?c)))) AS ?dist) .
    FILTER ( ?dist < 25 ) .
}
```

**UPDATE**

The problem is caused by this line `BIND ((2*lfn:sin-1(lfn:sqrt(?a))) AS ?c) .`. For some values of `lat` and `lon` (0.0) it returns `NaN`.

Comment: Minor comment: Don't reuse the `owl` prefix if possible, this might confuse people.

Comment: @AKSW: What do you mean by saying "don't reuse"? I appreciate if indicate how to improve this part.

Comment: I just meant that prefixes like `rdf`, `rdfs` ,`owl` and `xsd` are well-known prefixes for some defined vocabluaries.

Comment: @AKSW: Ah, ok, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding `IF` to the `BIND` statement:

```
BIND (IF(?c != "NaN"^^xsd:double,xsd:float(fn:round((6371*?c))),999999) AS ?dist)
```